# How to design a table(using listbox) in Windows Phone?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I could not able to design a table using listbox. For the past 5 days, am doing nothing but these things, I am totally naive to Windows Phone application development.For me, the problem is the **table that i'm designing will not fit into a single page**. I want the user to drag the table to view the off-contents. But using list box (particularly, listbox item) i could not able to achieve this. After this, i need to create dynamic rows to the table.Could anybody please help to create the table?

Comment: Could you give as any example what you've done so far? It could be easier then.

Comment: First i tried to do using gridview but in gridview i cant able to bind dynamic resource. Then i moved to listbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

Building a DataGrid Control for Silverlight for Windows Phone

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Building-a-DataGrid-Control-for-Silverlight-for-Windows-Phone-Part-1.aspx

This might help =)